# Short story involving a blue pyramid with human eyes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story is at least 20 years old. It involves a man who has these flashes of genius and then blacks out not remembering what he did. He has one of these flashes and when he comes to there is a blue pyramid with eyes in his house. While he is trying to figure this pyramid out every time he tries to pour himself a drink, whiskey I think, the liquid disappears before he can drink it. I do not remember if this was in Analog or just a collection of stories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

["Ex Machina"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?350031) by [Henry Kuttner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Kuttner), originally published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, April 1948](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57386+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v41n02_1948-04_cape1736#page/n5/mode/2up)) under the pseudonym [Lewis Padgett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Padgett) (which Kuttner shared with his wife [C. L. Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._L._Moore)).

The story is one of Kuttner's *Gallegher* stories, a series of five novelettes originally published in *Astounding* and collected in the book [*Robots Have No Tails*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?28378). Gallegher is a genius inventor, but only when he's drunk; he wakes up the next day with weird gadgets he invented the night before and no idea what they are for.

The following description of the story "Ex Machina" is excerpted from an Amazon.com Customer Review by [s.ferber](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3TN04P6649NDY/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=160125153X) of the collection *Robots Have No Tails*:

> The collection ends with a tale called "Ex Machina" (April '48 "ASF"), in which Gallegher, Grandpa and Joe all return one more time for another way-out adventure. In this one, Gallegher sobers up again, only to find an invisible speed drinker in his house, as well as a metallic gizmo with blue eyes staring at him. (This orbed object may bring to mind the blue-eyed doorknob from Kuttner and Moore's extremely psychedelic novella "The Fairy Chessmen," from 1946.) Here, Gallegher is commissioned by a safari expedition company to come up with a way of minimizing the inherent danger to its customers. The story finds Joe discovering philosophy for the first time, has Gallegher once again accused of murder by the dim-witted authorities, and provides another wacky explanation for all the preceding mishegas.

Comment: This reminds me of a story from **A Medicine for Melancholy** by Ray Bradbury where I think the main character's wife gives birth to a blue pyramid.

Comment: @rebusB Ray Bradbury's "blue pyramid" story is "Tomorrow's Child" aka "The Shape of Things" which has appeared in [a number of places](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64891) but not in [*A Medicine for Melancholy*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?874). You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v31n03_1948-02#page/n45/mode/2up).