# Series -- protagonist only invents when very drunk, puzzled by inventions when sobered

Tags: story-identification

A series of short stories, collected in a book, circa 1950..1958.

Protagonists name is Gallagher. In a typical story, he gets a development comission, gets drunk on beer, wakes up to discover that he has built a device, and has to figure out how it solves his client's problem.

He is accompanied by a robot that he built while under the influence. He doesn't know the purpose of the robot but does not dare dismantle it.

Comment: You could have googled “Gallagher drunk robot” and saw the book’s Wikipedia article as the first result :)

Comment: Rick and Morty had an episode in a similar vein ([S03E04 - Vindicators 3: The Return of Worldender](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Vindicators_3:_The_Return_of_Worldender))

Answer (score 15):

These are by Henry Kuttner, and are indeed known as the [Gallegher series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?38142).

The book may have been [Robots Have No Tails](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?28378) or [The Proud Robot](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?45693), both of which collect the stories. (The contents of the books appear to be identical except that the later one has an introduction).

(Note: Lewis Padgett is a pseudonym used by Kuttner)

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to this:  There are six Gallagher stories and both Robots Have No Tails and The Proud Robot contain all six.     http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?452     There was also a Henry Kuttner story with a somewhat similar character named Gunther but I forget the title at the moment.

Comment: isfdb only shows five stories in Robots Have No Tails. Ah, it lists Robots Have No Tails as part of the series.  So I think there are 5 stories and both books contain them all.

Comment: Margle - yes, I think you are right and Robots Have No Tails is merely the title of the first book.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because one question is about the series and the other is about a particular story, but we have had a question about this drunken inventor: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56006/short-story-involving-a-blue-pyramid-with-human-eyes/56010#56010